# How to efficiently do regular expression match on DataInputStream

Tags: java, regex, datainputstream

I have an requirement, whereby if given an `DataInputStream`, I will return back the handle to another `DataInputstream`, whereby I can filter out content which has specific text-patterns( obfuscated content which matches a regular expression).

## Could someone provide me any pointers as to how to approach the problem? Is there any library to do this?

Edited as per suggestion.

I want to build a filtering stream on top on org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream. This class ( FSDataInputStream) is part of Apache Hadoop-common project. The purpose is provide an handle of FSDataInputStream which also applied regular expression to the stream. I understand that FSDataInputStream is byte stream (please correct me if this is not the case) and we need to convert into character stream before we can apply the filter.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

The standard library offers a FilterInputStream (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html)

The idea is to subclass this class and override the methods and filter out the regular expressions before returning the data to the caller.

Since it extends InputStream it can be used anywhere an InputStream is expected.